# 401 Unauthorized Error When using JWT token to acces an API (Postman) Spring boot/Maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jwt

i have followed Dan Vega's tutorial on JWT token authorization. Everything works, even generating the Token when entering a valid username and password into postman. But when i try to acces any API, WITH that token, it gives me a error 401 Unauthorized.

**The security configuration file:**

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    public SecurityConfig(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager bedrijf() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("cezar")
                        .password("{noop}password")
                        .authorities("read")
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }
}
```

**The Token service:**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimsSet;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoderParameters;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class TokenserviceImplimentation {
    private final JwtEncoder encoder;

    public TokenserviceImplimentation(JwtEncoder encoder){
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    //In deze methode kan fouten zitten
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
            Instant now = Instant.now();
            String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
            JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                    .issuer("self")
                    .issuedAt(now)
                    .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                    .subject(authentication.getName())
                    .claim("scope", scope)
                    .build();
            return this.encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

**The Authentication controller:**

```
import com.Code.Pakket.management.service.TokenserviceImplimentation;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
@CrossOrigin
public class AcountController {
    private final TokenserviceImplimentation tokenserviceImplimentation;

    public AcountController(TokenserviceImplimentation tokenserviceImplimentation){
        this.tokenserviceImplimentation = tokenserviceImplimentation;
    }

    @PostMapping("/token")
    public String token(Authentication authentication) {
         String token = tokenserviceImplimentation.generateToken(authentication);
         return token;
    }
}
```

**The dependency's:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Code</groupId>
    <artifactId>Pakket-management</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Pakket-management</name>
    <description>Full stack application - Springboot &amp; React</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <sonar.organization>cezarpop12</sonar.organization>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.9.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**And finally the API im trying to acces (Home Controller):**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Principal principal) {
        return "Hello, " + principal.getName();
    }
}
```

I will leave a couple of screenshots from postman to show you guys what im doing there.

Any help would be apreciated.

[image: This is where i am retrieving a JWT token (This works fine!)]
[image: This is where i am trying to acces the Home Controller (API) with the retrieved token]

Comment: Most of the code above just aims at producing self-signed JWTs, which is, as explained in the he tutorial, unsafe compared to using an authorization-server. Choose an OIDC one (Keycloak, Okta, Auth0, or whatever) and follow [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) instead, things will get easier.

Comment: Oh thats unfortunate to hear :(( Do you recommend Auth0?

Comment: It depends if you prefer a hosted solution ("in the cloud") or an instance the you manage yourself ("on premise"). You could also use one solution in dev (Keycloak on your own machine) and an other one in production (Auth0, Okta, Amazon Cognito, or whatever your cloud provider proposes). The latest projects I worked on use Keycloak in prod, but they have a dedicated team for infrastructure with 24/7 monitoring and support...

Comment: Also, the 2nd and 3rd of the tutorials I pointed you to use a thin wrapper around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` which makes switching from an OIDC authorization-server provider to an other, just a matter of editing properties

Comment: Thanks alot! Appreciate it

Comment: I created a [pull-request](https://github.com/danvega/jwt/pull/5) on Dan Vega's repo to demo what, in my opinion, can be improved. Maybe should you read it (and compare how much simple is the code after) to make your own opinion.

Comment: That would be verry nice.